# Add a negation refinement filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-api

Using Search Query tool, I need to generate a query to retrieve items from a SharePoint list by filtering item properties based on a dropdown values(-,A,B,C,D).

My results should not include items with dropdown values(A,B,C):

Sample structure of query I am trying is :

```
<mysiteurl>/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:"Sample"&refinementfilters='ListDD:NOT("A,B,C")'
```

Like AND and OR, is there any other builtin operator for Exclude/Not Equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below works for me:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:Sample'&refinementfilters='and(Title:not("A"),Title:not("B"),Title:not("C"))'
```